# Why the promises chains does not work as expected (chaining tasks)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise, chain

What are the advantages using the chain with '.then' if it does not work like a expected:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    // A mock async action using setTimeout
    setTimeout(function() { resolve(10); }, 3000);
})

.then(function(num) { 
    console.log('first then: ', num); return num * 2; })

.then(function(num) { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log('second then: ', num); return num * 2; }, 500);
    })

.then(function(num) { 
    console.log('last then: ', num);
});

// RESULT!
// From the console:
// first then:  10
// last then:  undefined
// second then:  20
```

I was expecting for the following result:

```
// RESULT!
// From the console:
// first then:  10
// second then:  20
// last then:  40
```

Comment: Your second `then` calls the `setTimeout` function, but it won't wait for it to finish before your third `then` is run.  You'd need to have a callback for your `setTimeout` function.

Comment: I agree with @snapjs - think of it this way.  IF the `setTimeout` did NOT behave this way, every `setTimeout` would become a "waitfor" or some such effectively becoming a blocker of script execution which is not what you want, you want a "run after x time" here.  Note that your promise does a resolve, then runs the others which is different.

Comment: Thanks @snapjs, I expected more power from promises, that it works as a callback.

Comment: Instead of promise I'll have to use this ugly code... function doOne() {...; doTwo(out);}  function doTwo(in) {...; doThree(out);} ... and so on...

Comment: @BiruelRick Well you would have to actually *use* a promise in the `then` callback, it would have worked then. Use the same pattern with `new Promise` as you have at the start of your chain, and `return` that from the `then` callback. Promises do not - cannot - magically know about asynchronous callbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second *then* has to return another promise if you want the *third* then to fire after the timeout in the second *then*.

This version of your code will give you the desired result:

```js
new Promise(function (resolve) { 
    setTimeout(function() {
     resolve(10);
    }, 3000);
})
.then(function (num) { 
    console.log('first then: ', num); return num * 2;
})
.then(function (num) { 
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
     setTimeout(function () { 
            console.log('second then: ', num);
            resolve(num * 2);
        }, 500);
    });
})
.then(function (num) { 
    console.log('last then: ', num);
});
```

The reason why your code didn't work as expected was that the third *then* was invoked immediately after the second timeout started, with the result of the call to `setTimeout`, which is *undefined*.

I looks like you expected the result you are returning from the callback of the second timeout to be somehow passed as result of the second *then*, but that's not the way it works.

Comment: I was also considering posting a similar example :) I believe this is what the OP was attempting to do.

Comment: Thanks so much Patrick Hund! I thought that the third '.then' would only be fired after the return statement of the second '.then'. now I will to use another promise with resolve(). Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Glad to help! 